# Google Sheets yahoo finance importXML text not td data

Tags: google-sheets, yahoo-finance, google-sheets-formula

On SO I often see people inquiring about how to import data from the tables on yahoo finance. I'm trying to import the business description under the profile section from yahoo finance. It seems this would require the importxml function but I'm struggling. This is my function:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile", "//div[@data-reactid='139']")
```

I think my issue is related to "div" but not sure. Might anyone be able to provide guidance? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Sample formula:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//h2[@data-reactid='139']/../p")
```

- In this case, the URL of `http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/profile` is put in "A1".
- I used `//h2[@data-reactid='139']/../p` as the xpath.

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: Tanaike you are awesome! Thank you so much. This helps me learn more XML too. I had tried a number of variations but hadn't considered the "/.../p" at the end. Cheers mate!

Comment: @CayG Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.